# How to 'update' the connection string for the Database that my web app on production environment?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, production-environment

Right now, I have a connection string in my appsetings.json and I can use my local database to develop the application. This is a small hobby-project and I want to run the ASP.NET Core web-app just locally through ISS or something like that. Likewise, I will install MySQL on the target environment too.

But how do I set the connection string for the production environment so that when I am developing, the local string is used, and when I publish the app to the prod-env, the app automatically uses the other connection string?

- Database: MySQL
- ORM: Entity Framework Core
- Stack: ASP.NET Core MVC

Comment: How are you looking to host your app? If you're going to be doing it on Azure, you can define your prod connection string in Azure itself, so it's secure and not checked into source control.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to go should be to overload your "appsettings.json" with 1 for dev, and 1 for release.

The way this works is that the sln will use "appsettings.Development.json" when it detects the project is running under Debug mode and likewise it will use "appsettings.json" when it detects release/publish mode.

Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for more information. It might change depending on the core version you are using, but what you are looking for is "overloaded appsettings" or "enviroment variable appsettings", so do some more googling!